# Swagger.io OpenApi v3.0 declare default media type

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger.io Openapi V3.0

The generated openapi.yaml file declares the response content media type as `*/*` per default.
I would like the default response content media type to be `application/json`

I am aware that you can manually change the media type per response by doing:

```
@ApiResponse(description = "test"
        , content = @Content(
            mediaType = "application/json",
            schema = @Schema(
                implementation = Test.class
            )
        )
    )
```

But this approach is not optimal, since there are many responses that would need to be modified.

Is there a way to change mapstruct/openapi default media type?

Comment: What does `Mapstruct 1.4.2Final together with Swagger.io Openapi V3.0` mean?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev ah, sorry, I mistakenly thought we used Mapstruct annotations in combination with openapi v3.0. I have edited the question, thank you

Comment: How do you create an openapi file? What are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

while swagger-core does not currently have this feature, an alternative is to use JAX-RS and define @Produces("your/mediaType") on a class level.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html

Since openapi/swagger-core works with JAX-RS annotations but not the other way around, this still works for generating the openapi.yaml

**OLD POST**

The specific feature I was looking for has been requested to be implemented in OpenAPI ca. 2015
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/521

This is one of the threads describing the need for the feature. It seems implementation of that feature might come in OpenAPI v4.0, but not confirmed yet

Answer (score 0):

In Swagger (OpenAPI) version 3.0, the default media type for response content is */*, which means it can represent any media type. However, if you want to set a default response media type to application/json for all responses without explicitly specifying it for each response, you can achieve this by defining a global response in your OpenAPI specification.

Here's how you can do it in your OpenAPI YAML file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Your API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /your-endpoint:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:   # Set the default media type here
              schema:
                type: object   # Adjust this schema definition accordingly
        # Add other response codes here as needed
```

By defining the application/json media type under the content section in the responses section of your endpoint, you establish it as the default media type for the 200 response. You can do this for other response codes as needed.

This approach allows you to set a default media type for specific response codes without needing to specify it individually for each endpoint.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: You're absolutely amazing, thank you very much! Just for clarification: "/your-endpoint:" would refer to the provided path for each response? Or can it be a general path?
For example, if my API was reachable from "localhost:8080/api", and I have the paths "/api/cars" and "/api/customers", would I be able to just specify "/api" in my openapi yaml file to cover both cases?

Comment: So, if your API is reachable from "localhost:8080/api" and you have the paths "/api/cars" and "/api/customers," you should define these paths separately in your OpenAPI YAML file to accurately document and describe each endpoint.